# Trying to create a website in IIS by Power Shell script

Tags: powershell, iis

I have the following script:

```
$Logdir = $args[0]
$Description = $args[1]
$Domain = $args[2]
New-Item IIS:Sites$Description -Bindings (
    @{Protocol="http"; BindingInformation="*:80:$Domain"},
    @{Protocol="http"; BindingInformation="*:80:www.$Domain"}
) -PhysicalPath "$LogDirhttp"
```

I executed it as:

```
create.ps1 "C:\inetpubyusufozturk.info" "www.yusufozturk.info" "yusufozturk.info”
```

I got following error:-

> New-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'Bindings'. At C:\es\develop\ShareAspace\create.ps1:4 char:32
>   + New-Item IIS:Sites$Description -Bindings (@{Protocol="http";BindingIn ...
>   +                                ~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

I'm new in PS scripting. I don't know what is wrong? Also please inform me how to delete a website by power shell?

Comment: just fishing here, do you have iis installed on the pc you are developing on? if not try the script on a pc with iis. alternatively create the site without the bindings and set them afterwards with Set-Webbinding or Set-ItemProperty

Comment: I have iis installed. But if I remove the bindings and set it by hand, then the whole points of scripting is kind of pointless. I should make the whole website by the script

Comment: Obviously you would do it in the script and not by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`New-Item` doesn't have parameters named `-bindings` or `-physicalpath`.

I would use the `New-WebSite` cmdlet to create the site and the `Set-WebBinding` to set the bindings.

These cmdlets are in the WebAdministration module, which you're using if you have access to the IIS: drive.  Be sure to use this module in an elevated session (as administrator).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Actually what the OP is doing, is documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools

On one of my IIS servers...

```
Import-Module -Name WebAdministration

Get-Website | Select Name,ID,State,PhysicalPath

name             id state   physicalPath                 
----             -- -----   ------------                 
Default Web Site  1 Started %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot
kcd               2 Started C:\inetpub\kcd               



New-Item iis:\Sites\MyTestSite -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":80:MyTestSite"} -physicalPath c:\MyTest

Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings                                                         
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------                                                         
MyTestSite       3    Started    c:\MyTest                      http :80:MyTestSite                                              



Get-Website | Select Name,ID,State,PhysicalPath

name             id state   physicalPath                 
----             -- -----   ------------                 
Default Web Site  1 Started %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot
kcd               2 Started C:\inetpub\kcd               
MyTestSite        3 Started c:\MyTest   


Get-WebBinding 

protocol bindingInformation            sslFlags
-------- ------------------                --------
http     *:80:                                    0
http     192.168.1.3:80:kcd....                   0
http     :80:MyTestSite                           0
```

As for deleting the website, just use the Remove-Website cmdlet

Answer (score 0):

This is years after the OP has accepted an answer, but I just wanted to put it out there that I noticed that `New-Item ... -physicalPath` stopped working for me when I imported [IISAdministration](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-script-to-create-iis-website/) (after using commands from [WebAdministration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/?view=win10-ps).) This was on Windows2019 w/ PS 5.